# Hadoop 2.4 maven build OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: maven, hadoop, heap-memory

I was trying to build the complete source code of Hadoop on my mac. When I try building I constantly run into the error: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space". I tried to set the maven opts using the command: **export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m"** and export **MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m"**. But none of these solutions have helped me. I have a 4GB DDR3 RAM. 2.3 GHz intel core i5 processor. Please provide me the right direction.
Logs:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Apache Hadoop HDFS 2.4.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ hadoop-hdfs ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/harshavyaspalli/Sachin/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (create-testdirs) @ hadoop-hdfs ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/harshavyaspalli/Sachin/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/target/test-dir
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/harshavyaspalli/Sachin/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/target/test/data
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (create-jsp-generated-sources-directory) @ hadoop-hdfs ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/harshavyaspalli/Sachin/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/target/generated-sources/java
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jspc-maven-plugin:2.0-alpha-3:compile (hdfs) @ hadoop-hdfs ---
[WARNING] Compiled JSPs will not be added to the project and web.xml will not be modified, either because includeInProject is set to false or because the project's packaging is not 'war'.
Created dir: /Users/harshavyaspalli/Sachin/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/target/classes
[INFO] Compiling 8 JSP source files to /Users/harshavyaspalli/Sachin/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/target/generated-sources/java
[INFO] Built File: /block_info_xml.jsp
[INFO] Built File: /corrupt_files.jsp
[INFO] Built File: /corrupt_replicas_xml.jsp
[INFO] Built File: /decommission.jsp
[INFO] Built File: /dfsclusterhealth.jsp
[INFO] Built File: /dfshealth.jsp
[INFO] Built File: /dfsnodelist.jsp
[INFO] Built File: /nn_browsedfscontent.jsp
WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html for an explanation.
[INFO] Compiled completed in 0:00:00.579
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jspc-maven-plugin:2.0-alpha-3:compile (secondary) @ hadoop-hdfs ---
[WARNING] Compiled JSPs will not be added to the project and web.xml will not be modified, either because includeInProject is set to false or because the project's packaging is not 'war'.
[INFO] Compiling 1 JSP source file to /Users/harshavyaspalli/Sachin/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/target/generated-sources/java
[INFO] Built File: /status.jsp
WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html for an explanation.
[INFO] Compiled completed in 0:00:00.041
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jspc-maven-plugin:2.0-alpha-3:compile (journal) @ hadoop-hdfs ---
[WARNING] Compiled JSPs will not be added to the project and web.xml will not be modified, either because includeInProject is set to false or because the project's packaging is not 'war'.
[INFO] Compiling 1 JSP source file to /Users/harshavyaspalli/Sachin/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/target/generated-sources/java
[INFO] Built File: /journalstatus.jsp
WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html for an explanation.
[INFO] Compiled completed in 0:00:00.041
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jspc-maven-plugin:2.0-alpha-3:compile (datanode) @ hadoop-hdfs ---
[WARNING] Compiled JSPs will not be added to the project and web.xml will not be modified, either because includeInProject is set to false or because the project's packaging is not 'war'.
[INFO] Compiling 4 JSP source files to /Users/harshavyaspalli/Sachin/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/target/generated-sources/java
[INFO] Built File: /browseBlock.jsp
[INFO] Built File: /browseDirectory.jsp
[INFO] Built File: /dataNodeHome.jsp
[INFO] Built File: /tail.jsp
WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html for an explanation.
[INFO] Compiled completed in 0:00:00.073
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.5:add-source (add-jsp-generated-sources-directory) @ hadoop-hdfs ---
[INFO] Source directory: /Users/harshavyaspalli/Sachin/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/target/generated-sources/java added.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- hadoop-maven-plugins:2.4.0:protoc (compile-protoc) @ hadoop-hdfs ---
[WARNING] [protoc, --version] failed with error code 1
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- hadoop-maven-plugins:2.4.0:protoc (compile-protoc-datanode) @ hadoop-hdfs ---
[WARNING] [protoc, --version] failed with error code 1
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- hadoop-maven-plugins:2.4.0:protoc (compile-protoc-namenode) @ hadoop-hdfs ---
[WARNING] [protoc, --version] failed with error code 1
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- hadoop-maven-plugins:2.4.0:protoc (compile-protoc-qjournal) @ hadoop-hdfs ---
[WARNING] [protoc, --version] failed with error code 1
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.2:resources (default-resources) @ hadoop-hdfs ---
[INFO] Using default encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ hadoop-hdfs ---
[INFO] Compiling 587 source files to /Users/harshavyaspalli/Sachin/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:


The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Position$LineMapImpl.build(Position.java:139)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Position.makeLineMap(Position.java:63)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Scanner.getLineMap(Scanner.java:1113)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:512)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:550)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parseFiles(JavaCompiler.java:804)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:727)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:279)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:270)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileInProcess0(JavacCompiler.java:551)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileInProcess(JavacCompiler.java:526)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compile(JavacCompiler.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:678)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)

[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................ SUCCESS [  3.836 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM ......................... SUCCESS [  1.634 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations ......................... SUCCESS [  3.661 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies .......................... SUCCESS [  0.441 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM .................... SUCCESS [  2.310 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins ....................... SUCCESS [  4.806 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MiniKDC ............................. SUCCESS [  4.093 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth ................................ SUCCESS [  4.638 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples ....................... SUCCESS [  2.795 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common .............................. SUCCESS [01:38 min]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS ................................. SUCCESS [ 11.257 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project ...................... SUCCESS [  0.051 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS ................................ FAILURE [ 15.643 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS BookKeeper Journal ............. SKIPPED
```

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Me to faced the same problem but it was solved by using the this commands                                                   export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"

export JVM_ARGS="-XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

Answer (score 2):

This error is thrown by maven compiler plugin, Edit the pom file you are building, Under attribute maven-compiler-plugin add below configuration

```
 <configuration>
 <verbose>true</verbose>
 <fork>true</fork>
 </configuration>
```

This will clear heap space error.

Comment: Hi @bigdatauser, in which hadoop pom file do i add the above configuration.

Comment: In the directory, from where you are building, i.e Hadoop source directory

Comment: This worked for me when I hit the same java heap memory issue building hadoop 2.7.1 for Raspberry Pi 2 B. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For mac/linux users, just add an export statement to your ~/.profile (or similar file name). For example:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

and restart your shell. Worked for me

Comment: Hi @Kumar, thanks for the quick reply. I tried setting MAVEN_OPTS in .bash_profile on mac. But I still get the same error. When I try to build hadoop-hdfs-project individually it succeeds. My whole intention is to understand the Hadoops block placement strategy, do i need to build the whole project ?